# Origem dos sons fechado e aberto do "e" em Ele/Ela, Esse/Essa,

Tags: pronúncia, origem

Qual a origem dos sons fechado e aberto, respectivamente quanto se trata de gênero masculino e feminino, em algumas palavras como (o acento é só para marcar o som):

- Êle/Éla
- Êsse/Éssa (este/esta)
- Nêsse/Néssa (neste/nesta)
- Dêsse/Déssa (deste/desta)
- Aquêle/Aquéla
- *(talvez outras, não me lembro agora)*

Noto que um fenômeno similar acontece no francês e principalmente no espanhol. Mas no latim as palavras ille e illa o "i" tem o mesmo som, pelo menos nas pronúncias que encontrei na internet.

Comment: Tem gente muito mais qualificada para responder tua pergunta nesse site mas, até alguém aparecer, registro a observação de que parece contaminação da sílaba vizinha: em todos os seu exemplos o "e" é aberto ou fechado seguindo a característica da sílaba seguinte (ou seja, seria mais fácil/natural falar ***ê**lê* e ***é**lá*, que ***é**lê* e ***ê**lá*).

Comment: Em complemente à observação de stafusa, ***ê*** é semi-fechado; ***é*** e ***á*** são semi-aberto e aberto, portanto mais próximos.

Comment: Creio que seja um caso de metafonia (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafonia) em que as vogais da sílabas vizinhas alteram a sílaba tônica. O mesmo ocorreu com porco, ovo e porto, cujo plural permaneceu com vogal aberta.

Comment: Acho melhor deixar os acentos pra lá. Fica meio confuso assim. É só indicar os pronomes. Já não consigo seguir nada.

Comment: @stafusa Embora possa ser uma das possibilidades, já ouvi aprendizes de português como segunda língua, invertendo o tom do "e", entre ele e ela, aliás, eles demoram a pronunciar corretamente conforme o gênero, por não ter diacríticos (acentos).

Comment: @Luciano Sim, há estudantes que mal conseguem sequer perceber, ao ouvir, qual é a diferença entre esses sons abertos e fechados (e essas palavras, assim como "vovô" e "vovó" soam essencialmente idênticos para eles). Quando falei em "natural/fácil' tinha mesmo só falantes nativos em mente.

Answer (score 3):

É um fenomeno de **metafonia**, assim como o famoso fenômeno de *umlaut* das línguas germânicas! O que ocorreu foi que a primeira vogal de "ela"/"essa" foi mais aberta por influência da vogal seguinte, que é um /a/.

Portanto, o i-curto do latim gerou um [e] em português, e este [e], posteriormente, foi aberto por influência da vogal que vinha depois, coisa que não ocorreu com "ele".